# Jerky scaling of graphics when resizing panel

Tags: c#, events

I have a panel in which I do some custom drawing. To make sure the graphics scale proportionally when the panel is resized I use the `Transform` property of my `Graphics`.

```
private void panelGraph_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var gfx = e.Graphics;
    gfx.Transform = BuildTransform(e.ClipRectangle);
    var width = 1.0f / gfx.Transform.Elements[0];
    var white = new Pen(Color.White, width);
    gfx.DrawLine(white, new PointF(-1.0f, -1.0f), new PointF(1.0f, -1.0f));
    gfx.DrawLine(white, new PointF(-1.0f, -1.0f), new PointF(-1.0f, 1.0f));
}
```

The matrix from `BuildTransform` maps an area with width and height [-2, 2] to the area of `e.ClipRectangle`.

The code works, sort of. The problem is that when I resize the panel the scaling of my graphics isn't smooth but happens in discrete steps. If I add the following line in my paint-function:

```
Console.WriteLine("Paint {0} {1}", e.ClipRectangle.Width, e.ClipRectangle.Height);
```

I get output like this when I slowly resize the window:

```
Paint 1 815
Paint 1 815
Paint 1 815
Paint 751 815
Paint 1 815
Paint 753 815
Paint 1 813
Paint 754 811
```

What's causing this and how can I fix it?

**EDIT:** The problem isn't deterministic but seems to be dependent on how fast I resize the window(!). If I slowly, slowly resize the window I can get it nearly arbitrarily large without the size of my graphics changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you resize your window, the control will only invalidate the area that needs to be invalidated. Hence if you make it larger, it will assume that the already existing rectangle is ok and will invalidate the new area that the enlargement made visible. Since you obviously need to invalidate your *entire* control when you resize it, add a resize eventhandler and invalidate your control there. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Aha, I think i understand my output now. The clip rectangle is the area that needs repainting, so when I just adjust the vertical size of the window by say one pixel I get a clip size of something like `654, 1`. As soon as I resize it horizontally as well the entire region will need to be redrawn though.

Comment: Yep! WinForms try to optimize the repainting for you. Windows will normally collect areas and use the smallest rectangle containing them all for the invalitation process. Quite often you need to override this behaviour if you want to have smooth graphics, i.e. in user interaction. You could also take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957573/winforms-how-to-speed-up-invalidate

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, `ClipRectangle` isn't what you need, use `Bounds` instead.

Paint message always comes with clipping area that is required to REPAINT, and it is less or equal to whole control area, depending of how much of the control was obscured and was now revealed and needs repainting.

Comment: I experimentally calculated my transform from the size provided in the repaint event but I still get the same weirdness.

Comment: Use control BOUNDS, as told, please try with it.  Size provided in repaint event is something you don't want to use here.  If it works, I'll try to explain why.

Comment: I added the explanation that should reassure you somehow :)

Comment: This is definitely right that ClipRectangle is the wrong thing to be using.  I'd actually recommend ClientRectangle over Bounds though.

Comment: @Will: ClipRectange SHOULD be the area that is redrawn, but not the area to be used in SCALING.  Right?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `Form.DoubleBuffer` property to true.

Comment: This only removes the flickering (which is nice of course), the actual scaling problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a composite of other people's correct answers:

- You should override/handle the resizing event and invalidate the whole window
- You should use ClientRectangle and not e.ClipRectangle when calculating the scaling for the window.